# Возникает ошибка в импорте данных в pgsql в скрипте ruby

Tags: postgresql, ruby

Есть такая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE public.partitioned_purchases (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    project character varying NOT NULL,
    title character varying NOT NULL,
    purchased_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    quantity integer NOT NULL,
    price double precision NOT NULL,
    sum double precision NOT NULL,
    auto_category character varying,
    manual_category character varying,
    link_item_id character varying,
    item_id character varying,
    age integer,
    city character varying,
    shop character varying,
    address character varying,
    user_id character varying,
    user_date_of_birth date,
    user_gender character varying,
    user_phone character varying,
    user_email character varying,
    user_city character varying,
    user_vk_uid character varying,
    user_ok_uid character varying,
    user_fb_uid character varying,
    receipt_id character varying NOT NULL,
    receipt_total double precision NOT NULL,
    receipt_fn character varying NOT NULL,
    receipt_fd character varying NOT NULL,
    receipt_fpd character varying NOT NULL,
    receipt_inn character varying,
    receipt_qr_string character varying,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    promotion_title character varying,
    receipt_created_at timestamp without time zone,
    cashback_currency public.citext,
    cashback_value integer
) PARTITION BY RANGE (receipt_created_at);

-- CREATE TABLE partitioned_purchases_y2022m03 PARTITION OF partitioned_purchases
--     FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-03-01') TO ('2022-04-01');
-- CREATE TABLE partitioned_purchases_y2022m04 PARTITION OF partitioned_purchases
--     FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-04-01') TO ('2022-05-01');

CREATE SEQUENCE public.partitioned_purchases_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.partitioned_purchases_id_seq OWNED BY public.partitioned_purchases.id;
ALTER TABLE public.partitioned_purchases ADD CONSTRAINT partitioned_purchases_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, receipt_created_at);
ALTER TABLE ONLY public.partitioned_purchases ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.partitioned_purchases_id_seq'::regclass);
CREATE INDEX index_partitioned_purchases_on_receipt_created_at ON public.partitioned_purchases USING btree (receipt_created_at);
CREATE INDEX index_partitioned_purchases_on_created_at ON public.partitioned_purchases USING btree (created_at);
CREATE INDEX index_partitioned_purchases_on_link_item_id ON public.partitioned_purchases USING btree (link_item_id);
CREATE INDEX index_partitioned_purchases_on_manual_category ON public.partitioned_purchases USING btree (manual_category);
CREATE INDEX index_partitioned_purchases_on_manual_category_and_receipt_id ON public.partitioned_purchases USING btree (manual_category, receipt_id);
CREATE INDEX index_partitioned_purchases_on_project ON public.partitioned_purchases USING btree (project);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_partitioned_purchases_on_project_and_link_item_id ON public.partitioned_purchases USING btree (project, link_item_id, receipt_created_at);
CREATE INDEX index_partitioned_purchases_on_receipt_id ON public.partitioned_purchases USING btree (receipt_id);
CREATE INDEX index_partitioned_purchases_on_updated_at ON public.partitioned_purchases USING btree (updated_at);
```

и есть такой код импорта

```
require 'csv'

class ImportPurchases
  def run(file_path = nil)
    values = []
    batch_size = 1_000
    batch_number = 0
    start = Time.current.to_i
    file_path = Rails.root.join('purchase_data', 'purchases.csv') if file_path.blank?
    headers = CSV.open(file_path, 'r', &:first)
    columns = PartitionedPurchase.column_names - %w[id created_at updated_at]
    conflict_target = %w[project link_item_id]
    key_update = { conflict_target: conflict_target, columns: columns }
    CSV.foreach(file_path).each_with_index do |row, idx|
      next if idx.zero?

      values.push(row)
      next unless values.count % batch_size == 0

      batch_number += 1
      PartitionedPurchase.import(headers, values, validate: true, on_duplicate_key_update: key_update)
      values = []
      logger.info("Batch number #{batch_number} | seconds spended #{Time.current.to_i - start}")
    end
    return if values.blank?

    PartitionedPurchase.import(headers, values, validate: true, on_duplicate_key_update: key_update)
  end

  def logger
    @logger ||= Logger.new('log/import_purchases.log')
  end
end
```

эти воркеры выполняются в saidkiq

и при импорте возникает такая ошибка

```
PG::CheckViolation: ERROR:  no partition of relation "partitioned_purchases" found for row
DETAIL:  Partition key of the failing row contains (receipt_created_at) = (2023-05-03 17:11:34).


еще такая раньше выскакивала, я немного индексы подправил 

PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification : INSERT INTO "partitioned_purchases"
```

Хотел спросить совета у экспертов по pg, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Ну, наверное, дело в том, что указанная дата 2023-05-03 ни в одну из имеющихся партиций не лезет...

Comment: при импорте каждой записи отдельно в пустую таблицу, эта ошибка возникает для каждого инсерта. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: не специалист в постгре, но думаю ошибка возникает так: в цикле в рамках одной транзакции идет вставка в таблицу, в какой-то момент бд решает создать новую партицию, но видит, что есть активные транзакции и не может ее создать. а поскольку место в партиции закончилось, транзакция падает с ошибкой.

Comment: А еще есть варианты из-за чего ошибки сыпятся?